# Mining aeon but the balance is still zero

Tags: aeon, mining

I want to solo-mine Aeon, so I downloaded AEON-0.9.12.0-WIN64.ZIP from https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/releases, registered my wallet using the simplewallet, and synced the blockchain in the Aeon daemon.

Then I started mining in simplewallet using `start_mining` 
but I'm waiting for two days and if I check my balance it's still 0.  I'm using 99% of CPU and 6GB of RAM... How do I know I'm mining? What is the problem?

Details:

If I run `show_hr`, it shows me this: "hashrate: 312.6667"

When I start aeond, it shows me this:

> Starting... aeon v0.9.12.0() Module folder: C:\Users\memox\AEON\aeond.exe Initializing p2p server... Binding on 0.0.0.0:11180 Net service binded on 0.0.0.0:11180 Attempting to add IGD port mapping. No IGD was found. P2p server initialized OK Initializing cryptonote protocol... Cryptonote protocol initialized OK Initializing core rpc server... Binding on 127.0.0.1:11181 Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 11181 Initializing core... Loading blockchain...

Comment: In the window in which you're running the daemon (aeond), what happens when you enter the command `show_hr` ? It should tell you your current hash-rate.

Comment: yes, if i put show_hr show me this: hashrate: 312.6667

Comment: when i start the aeond show me this:Starting...
aeon v0.9.12.0()
Module folder: C:\Users\memox\AEON\aeond.exe
Initializing p2p server...
Binding on 0.0.0.0:11180
Net service binded on 0.0.0.0:11180
Attempting to add IGD port mapping.
No IGD was found.
P2p server initialized OK
 Initializing cryptonote protocol...
Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
Initializing core rpc server...
Binding on 127.0.0.1:11181
Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 11181
Initializing core...
Loading blockchain...

Comment: A while ago, I asked [a question about how to calculate mining rates](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/are-solo-mining-yield-calculations-like-dice-or-playing-card-calculations). Two helpful people told me that the formula that I quoted was *nearly* correct (*e.g.* it doesn't allow for network latency). So what happens if we plug **your** hash rate into that formula? The network hash rate is 911908 right now, so you have a 99% chance of finding at least one block if your mine for 37 days. Or, using the same formula, you have to mine for 5 days and 15 hours to get a 50% chance.

Comment: …but the network hash rate may change!

Comment: that is for find a new block?!? aeond only works for mine new blocks?!? 
I thought it was mining similar to minergate 
I'm wrong?

Comment: You're **solo** mining, so you're looking for blocks. Your reward when you find a block is currently about 17 AEON. With your hash rate, there's a 99% chance that you will acquire at least 17 AEON if you mine for about 37 days (actually, slightly longer than that for reasons explained in [previous answers](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4055/1425)).

Answer (score 1):

From the output you gave, you seem to be mining just fine.

Your wallet balance will increase when you find a block. Blocks are found randomly, but a probability which depends on the network hash rate and your own. Roughly, you can expect to find 100 * 312 / 3000000 = 0.01% [1] of Aeon blocks. As there are 360 Aeon blocks in a day, you will find a block every 26 days on average. Note the *on average*, as variance can be large for small hash rate compared to the network hash rate.

Once you found a block (the daemon will point it out), you will have to refresh your wallet so it sees the incoming aeon.

[1] 312 H/s is your hash rate, and 3000000 H/s is the current network hash rate. At the time of your post, the network hash rate was closer to 1000000 H/s (see http://chainradar.com/aeon/chart), which would make the answer closer to a block every 9 days on average.